# Can I pipe a list of usernames to useradd?

Tags: linux, bash, pipe

I have a collection of folders that I'm filtering down and need to create user accounts to go with them.  Can I pipe the output from my `grep` to `useradd` as usernames?

Context: FTP migration.  Moving to a Linux FTP server from Windows, but the storage is remaining where it is.  The folders are old FTP user folders, and the folder names match the FTP login names.  Looking at:

```
ls /media/OldFTP | grep -Ev '^[[:digit:]]{4}|^P[[:digit:]]{4}|^W[[:digit:]]{4}' | useradd -M -g ftpusers -N -p [encrytedPassword]
```

I'm trying to pass the output of my grep search to the username field for useradd.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the `encryptedPassword` will be the same for every user, you can use `xargs -n1 <cmd>` to run a command once for each argument passed on stdin.

```
ls /media/OldFTP |
    grep -Ev '^[[:digit:]]{4}|^P[[:digit:]]{4}|^W[[:digit:]]{4}' |
    xargs -n1 -d'\n' useradd -M -g ftpusers -N -p [encryptedPassword]
```

Comment: Ah xargs! I always forget about xargs.

Comment: I like it!  I was hoping not to have to loop through.  And unfortunately, yes all of them will have the same password :(.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You might need to use a `for` loop. Something like:

```
for user in `ls /media/OldFTP | grep -Ev '^[[:digit:]]{4}|^P[[:digit:]]{4}|^W[[:digit:]]{4}'`
do
   # initialize user's password somehow.
   encrytedPassword=`openssl rand -base64 10 | tr -cd '[:alnum:]' | cut -c1-10`
   useradd -M -g ftpusers -N -p $encrytedPassword $user
done
```